# CSS issue with div positioning

Tags: css

Hi am having an issue with the margin auto of my website where i have a wrapper div with the width set to 1000px and the margins top and bottom to 0 and left and right to auto. I have a navigation menu in the side bar, where i used java script to replace the same div with different tables. when i click a link in the menu the wrapper shifts right some px and the comes to original, I don't want that action i want the wrapper to be static and not to vary at any time. how can i achieve that.

when i set the margin to just 0, so problem with positioning. But i want the wrapper to be centered.

here is the demo:

http://techiedreams.com/projects/test/new/admin/index.php

Here is my css code:

```
body {
background-color:#E2E3E4;
color:#333;
font-size: 12px;
}

#wrapper {
background-color:#ffffff;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content {
width:780px;
float:right;
}

#sidebar {
width:150px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #EDE9DE;
margin-bottom:25px;
}

#footer {
clear:both;
margin:0 auto;
width:1000px;
height:44px;
border-top:1px solid #EDE9DE;
}
```

Please check the demo for HTML

Comment: try css property word-wrap: break-word and also try set this attribute -->  overflow: hidden --> also check that no other css code or js code is changing width when you click the link.

Comment: @sajawikio Sorry a small found, width is not varied but the position is varying. entire wrapper is being pushed to the right. I feel issue with the margin auto for the wrapper.

Comment: yes try to set margin 0 for everything and see if fixes it. 0 auto means equivalent to 0 auto 0 auto and means will be auto left and right so centering it - is probably ok but I bet that something has to be just margin 0 0 0 0 somewhere - you are probably right. I recommend take out all margins especially the ones saying just margin-left and just margin-right in your code for example.

Comment: @sajawikio When i set the margin to just 0 then no problem with the positioning, but i want that wrapper to be centered :/

Comment: It sounds like your javascript is changing something important.

Comment: Where is your HTML?  How can we fix your layout when we can't see it?

Comment: You posted some standard CSS and claim it doesn't work without providing any further evidence of such.  Please post your HTML and a demo, or close the question.

Comment: @Sparky672 Hi, just updated the question. if u need i can provide a demo

Comment: Please post your generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: @j08691 sorry for the php just updated with the html

Comment: @sajawikio here is the demo:

http://techiedreams.com/projects/test/new/admin/index.php

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match up. You've got at least two extra `</div>` and one extra `</table>` after the `</form>` tag. If you actually formatted your HTML (indenting the tags properly, I mean), you'd spot it quickly. This is probably not the root cause of your problem, however.

Comment: @Sparky672 here is the demo: techiedreams.com/projects/test/new/admin/index.php

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry for the code, its a rough edit of the original, but i provided a demo with the clean edited code have a look

Comment: I am not seeing anything shift at all.  However, if the window is made too short for longer content, a vertical scrollbar appears.  On most browsers, the viewport area is not included with the space taken up by a scrollbar, so the content may _appear_ to shift over just enough to make room for the scrollbar.

Comment: @Sparky672 Hi, click on the link 'One' and then 'Two' you can see slight shift when clicked on One and then when you click on two it shifts back.

Comment: Like I said, it only shifts just enough to make room for the scrollbar.  When my window is taller, there is no shifting at all.  Question should be closed as the reported "problem" is the normal browser behavior.

Comment: @Sparky672 Sorry!! you are absolutely right when the scroll bar appears it looks like shifted some pixels, but is there any recommended way to get rid of that shift.

Comment: That's just the way the browser behaves!  Your content is not shifting... it's the viewport moving over to make room for the scrollbar.

Comment: @Sparky672 what i mean to ask is keeping the position if the window static even when when the scroll bar appears.

Comment: @Sparky672 Is there any other way that i can center the content with out the margin: auto;

Comment: Since every browser has default scrollbars of various widths and scrollbar styles are usually part of operating system, it's not worth the huge amount of effort to compensate for something so inconsequential. Again, your content is centered... your CSS is working... and your browser is behaving exactly as expected.

Comment: Sorry if my comment dint make any sense, but some how i want to achieve that

Comment: Your comment made sense.  Why you'd want to do this makes no sense.  This has been discussed before, you just need to use the search function.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463200/absolute-div-shifts-when-scrollbar-is-present

Comment: Thanks Thanks a lot for the finding!! @Sparky672 i ill close the question. may be you could post the answer so that it ill be useful for others.

Comment: Sorry i just got ur comment thanks. but the post was straight forward for the problem.. but here its a problem finding discussion, anyways thanks for finding me a post of my problem resolved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, this question should be closed as there is nothing in the HTML/CSS causing the reported issue.  The OP is seeing a shift caused by the normal appearance of the vertical scrollbars.

One typical workaround has been to force the vertical scrollbar to be visible all the time, even when it's not needed.  This is not compatible with certain older browsers.

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

[Absolute div shifts when scrollbar is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463200/absolute-div-shifts-when-scrollbar-is-present)

I strongly prefer to make no fix and just allow the browser to behave normally, as most visitors expect it.